# Remove an element in Python list with partial word in list

Tags: python, list, filter, delete-row

I have a list that looks like this and I've tried the following code and nothing seems to work. My list called "ss" looks like this and I'm trying to remove any elements with "Sheet" in list:

```
ss = ['14', '13', '11', '10', '9', '8', '6', '3', '2', '1', '0', '7', '4', '12', '5', 'Sheet12', 'Sheet1']
```

I have tried variations of this and they do nothing:

```
ssnew = list(filter( lambda s: not (s[0:4]=="Sheet"), ss))
```

or,

```
newss = {ss.replace("Sheet","")for x in ss}
```

I need my new list `newss` to look like this -->

```
newss = ['14', '13', '11', '10', '9', '8', '6', '3', '2', '1', '0', '7', '4', '12', '5']
```

Comment: Both of your approaches were nearly correct: `list(filter(lambda s: not s[0:5]=="Sheet", ss))` -> your slice was one off, `{x.replace("Sheet","") for x in ss}` -> you tried replace on the `list ss` not the `string x` values. The second method only works if all values are unique and the rest of the 'sheet' values have duplicates in the `list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a comprehension:

```
>>> [i for i in ss if not i.startswith('Sheet')]
['14',
 '13',
 '11',
 '10',
 '9',
 '8',
 '6',
 '3',
 '2',
 '1',
 '0',
 '7',
 '4',
 '12',
 '5']
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you do mention that list elements should not contain "Sheet" with no other requirement, then this list comprehension is correct:

```
print([x for x in ss if 'Sheet' not in x])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be:

```
lst = [i for i in ss if i.isdigit()]
print(lst)
```